# Pyodbc not using default database when running from SSMS?

Tags: python, ssms, pyodbc

I created a python script that uses pyodbc to connect to SQL, runs a simple select query, and uses xlsxwriter to export the results to Excel.

Everything works great when I run the script from VS Code. However, when I execute the script from SQL Server Management Studio, I get an "invalid object name" error returned because it's not using my default database for my account, and can't find the table I'm selecting from.

I need to be able to have it just use whatever default database is set for the current user running the script. I can't find anything in searching on how to do this. Does anyone know how? I also don't understand why it works from VS Code, but not when I execute the script form SSMS?

Here's my python code that creates the connection string and query and runs it (works fine in VS Code):

```
import pyodbc

#Create SQL connection
sql_conn_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=localhost;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(sql_conn_string)
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()

#Run SQL query
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY 1, 2, 3 ASC"
cursor.execute(sql_query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Here's what I'm using to execute the script in SSMS:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'C:\Python39\python.exe "C:\MyScript.py"';  
GO
```

Error returned:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'MyTable'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I tried setting my database in SSMS before executing the Python script, but it still gives the same error.

I tried adding "INITIALCATALOG=dbo" to the connection string, prepending "dbo." to the table name in the SELECT query, and wrapping the table name in brackets. None of these worked though.

Comment: Don't forget, `xp_cmdshell` doesn't run under *your* credentials, it runs under the service accounts. Also, why are you still using SQLNCLI? That was deprecated in 2012. You should really be using the latest OLEDB or ODBC driver.

Comment: @ThomA - Yea I'm just realizing that now. I figured SQL would just use whatever account is executing the xp_cmdshell command, but of course not. Thanks for the tip about the driver. No idea about that since the driver is still available and works.

Comment: It is still available, yes (Microsoft leave them available for old systems) but in new work you shouldn't be using SQLNCLI any more. It's doesn't support anything after SQL Server 2014 and it's no longer shipped with SQL Server since the 2022 release.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else reminded me, xp_cmdshell runs under the service account, which means the python script won't see the default database on your account. So, I solved this by updating my python script to read command line arguments, and I'm passing in the database name that way.

```
import sys
import pyodbc

db_name = sys.argv[1]

#Create SQL connection
sql_conn_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=" + db_name + ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(sql_conn_string)
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
```

```
DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(1000) = ''
        ,@DBName NVARCHAR(128) = 'Database_Name'
SET @Cmd = 'C:\Python310\python.exe "C:\MyScript.py" ' + @DBName;
EXEC xp_cmdshell @Cmd;
GO
```